# Equidistribution of $\{\sqrt{p}: p \text{ primes }\}$ modulo 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

I am trying to show  $\{\sqrt{p}: p \text{ primes }\}$ is equidistributed modulo 1. Using Weyl's criterion, it is sufficient to show for each nonzero integer $k$,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x}e(k\sqrt{n}) \Lambda(n) =o(x), \text{ as } x \to \infty.
\end{equation}

I found an exercise on chapter 13 "sum over primes" in Iwaniec H., Kowalski E. - Analytic number theory regarding this: it's the exercise 2 on page 348:
for any real number $\alpha \neq 0$,
$$
\sum_{n\le x} e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \Lambda(n) \ll_\alpha  x^{\frac{5}{6}} (\log x)^4.
$$
The idea is to use the following Vaughan's identity and estimate each sum separately: Let $y,z \geq 1$, then
$$
\Lambda(n)=\sum_{\substack{b \mid n\\ b \leq y}} \mu(b) \log \frac{n}{b}-\sum_{\substack{bc \mid n\\ b \leq y, c \leq z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)+\sum_{\substack{bc \mid n\\ b > y, c >z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)+R(n),
$$
where $R(n)=0$ when $n>z$, and $R(n)=\Lambda(n)$ when $n \leq z$.

I came up with the following lemmas as some basic preparation:

1. For any real number $\alpha> 0$,
   $$
   \sum_{n\le x} e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \ll x^{\frac{1}{2}} \alpha^{-1}+\alpha^2,
   $$
   where the implicit constant does not depend on $\alpha$. (Using Van der Corput Method)
2. For any real number $\alpha > 0$, $N \leq x$, and any complex numbers $\beta_m,\gamma_n$ with $|\beta_m| \leq 1$ and $|\gamma_n| \leq 1$, we have
   $$
   A(M,N)=\sum_{M<m \leq 2M} \sum_{N<n \leq 2N}  \beta_m \gamma_n e(\alpha \sqrt{mn}) \ll MN^{1/2} + M^{1/4} N^{3/4}\alpha^{-1/2}(\log N)^{1/2}+N^{5/4} \alpha.
   $$
3. For any real number $\alpha > 0$, $N \leq x$, and any complex numbers $\beta_m$ with $|\beta_m| \leq 1$, we have
   $$
   B(x; N)=\sum_{N<n \leq 2N} |\sum_{mn \leq x} \beta_m e(\alpha \sqrt{mn})| \ll N^{1/2} x^{1/2}+x^{3/4} \alpha^{-1/2} (\log x)^{1/2}+x^{5/4} N^{-3/4} \alpha.
   $$
4. (Use lemma 2 and lemma3, Estimate for bilinear form) For any real number $\alpha \neq 0$, and any complex numbers $\beta_m, \gamma_n$ with $|\beta_m| \leq 1, |\gamma_n| \leq 1$, $M,N<\sqrt{x}$, we have
   $$
   \sum_{\substack{mn \leq x\\ m>M,n>N}} \beta_m \gamma_n e(\alpha \sqrt{mn}) \ll  x^{3/4}+x^{3/4} \alpha^{-1/2} (\log x)^{3/2}+x^{5/4} (N^{-3/4}+M^{-3/4})\alpha +x^{5/8}\alpha \log x +MN.
   $$

---

By Vaughan's idenity, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\le x} e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \Lambda(n)
&= \sum_{\substack{n\le x\\ b \mid n\\ b \leq y}} \mu(b) e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \log \frac{n}{b}-\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ bc \mid n\\ b \leq y, c \leq z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)e(\alpha \sqrt{n})\\
& \quad +\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ bc \mid n\\ b > y, c >z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)e(\alpha \sqrt{n})+O(\sum_{n \leq z} \Lambda(n)).
\end{align*}

For the first sum, using lemma1 and partial summation, we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\ b \mid n\\ b \leq y}} \mu(b) e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \log \frac{n}{b}
&=\sum_{\substack{bl\le x\\ b \leq y}} \mu(b) e(\alpha \sqrt{bl}) \log l \\
&\ll \sum_{b \leq y} |\sum_{l \leq x/b} e(\alpha \sqrt{bl}) \log l |\\
&\ll_{\alpha} x^{1/2} \log x \log y+y^2 \log x.
\end{align*}

For the second sum, using lemma1 and partial summation, we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ bc \mid n\\ b \leq y, c \leq z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)e(\alpha \sqrt{n})
&=\sum_{\substack{bcl\le x \\ b \leq y, c \leq z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)e(\alpha \sqrt{bcl}) \\
&\ll \sum_{b \leq y, c \leq z} |\mu(b) \Lambda(c)| |\sum_{bcl \leq x} e(\alpha \sqrt{bcl})|\\
&\ll \sum_{b \leq y, c \leq z}  |\sum_{bcl \leq x} e(\alpha \sqrt{bcl})| \Lambda(c)\\
&\ll_{\alpha} \sum_{b \leq y, c \leq z}  (x^{1/2} (bc)^{-1}+bc) \Lambda(c)\\
&\ll x^{1/2} \log y\log z+y^2z^2. 
\end{align*}

For the third sum, using lemma 4, it is easy to show that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ bc \mid n\\ b > y, c >z}} \mu(b) \Lambda(c)e(\alpha \sqrt{n})  
&=\log x \sum_{\substack{bk\le x \\ b > y, k >z}} \mu(b) \gamma_k e(\alpha \sqrt{bk}).  
\ll_{\alpha}
x^{3/4} (\log x)^{5/2}+x^{5/4} (y^{-3/4}+z^{-3/4})\log x+yz\log x.
\end{align*}

However, it seems some of my estimates could be improved, because based on the above estimate, there is no way to choose y,z such that
$$
\sum_{n\le x} e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \Lambda(n) =o(x).
$$
And the main issue here is that the $y^2z^2$ term from the second estimate seems to be too large, and this comes from the $\alpha^2$ term from lemma 1( the estimate for standard exponential sum). I had some ideas that could improve the $\alpha^2$ term to $\alpha^{3/2}$, but I guess $\alpha^{3/2}$ is still not good enough.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much！

Updated 1: I guess I figured out how to do this, for lemma 2 and lemma 3, we can take advantage that $n>N$ and use an improved version of lemma1.

Updated 2: Could someone point out what is the best known upper bound for
$$
\sum_{n\le x} e(\alpha \sqrt{n}) \Lambda(n)
$$

Comment: i don't see how $y^2z^2$ comes from the $\alpha^2$ term from lemma 1. specifically, I don't see how you got $x^{1/2} (bc)^{-1}+bc$.

Comment: For fixed $b,c$, $$|\sum_{bcl \leq x} e(\alpha \sqrt{bcl})| 
\ll x^{1/2} (bc)^{-1} \alpha^{-1}+ \alpha^2 bc$$ follows easily from lemma 1. The sum is over $l \leq x/bc$, and the "$\alpha$" in lemma 1 will be replaced $\alpha \sqrt{bc}$.

Comment: I still don't see how you got the bound $x^{1/2}(bc)^{-1}+bc$. Should the $\ll$ be $\ll_\alpha$?

Comment: Oh yes, that's a typo. I have corrected that.

Comment: For the first 100,000 primes, the first digit after the decimal point is distributed as $$\{\{0, 9904\}, \{1, 10060\}, \{2, 10042\}, \{3, 9941\}, \{4, 10059\},\\ \{5, 9967\}, \{6, 10069\}, \{7, 9973\}, \{8, 10065\}, \{9, 9920\}\}$$ according to Mathematica with 10 Mod[Sqrt[Prime[Range[10^5]]], 1] // Floor // Tally // Sort